# What causes the list alert option on updates on items within a view to not appear?

Tags: list-view, alert, large-lists

I have multiple large lists, and I'm able to specify a view to filter my alerts on both one of the smallest lists and the largest of those lists (6k and 50k items). The smallest list has 5.35k items, and the filtered alert on "Someone changes an item that appears in the following view" option does not appear. They're all lists rather than libraries and structurally very similar.

[image]

versus

[image]

What would cause this difference?

Comment: Do both lists have multiple views?

Comment: Yes. They all have multiple views.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of filtering on workflow columns in these views that could prevent them from sending an alert?

Comment: On some views, I have filters. I have those same types of filters on the other lists as well. I have some views without filters. They're all the same, but the option to select any view does not appear on this one particular list.